# IIF Statement with OR in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to set this query up so that if the length of the EMPID field is not = to 7 or 11, it places 7 0's into the field. I think I have the logic down, but I'm getting an error message saying that the number of arguments in the IIF statement is incorrect. Any help?

```
  IIf(Len([EMPID]=7 or Len([EMPID]=11,[EMPID],"0000000")));
```

Comment: `IIf(Len([EMPID])=7 or Len([EMPID])=11, [EMPID], "0000000");` you messed the parentheses.

Comment: This was solved

Comment: Your parentheses are off.  I think this is a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
IIf(Len([EMPID])=7 or Len([EMPID])=11,[EMPID],"0000000");
```

Comment: That worked. Guess it wasn't as hard as I was making it out to be. Appreciate the help!